# configure: error: assembler too old, .cfi_personality support missing

Tags: installation, glibc

I have tried one day to install glibc-2.11 for sublime text.
My system is centoS 5.5 64, every time I attempted to install glibc-2.11, it ends up with `configure: error: assembler too old, .cfi_personality support missing`. I know it is that my system is too old. But I want to know if there is anyone have good ways to solve it.

P.S. The app of sublime test requires GLIBC 2.11.

Comment: Did you succeed in building it and running sublime? I am facing the same issue when building glibc in rhel 5.5 for sublime text 2.

Answer (score 1):

> I know it is that my system is too old.

Please note that *unless done very carefully*, updating glibc may easily render your system un-bootable.

The solution to `configure` problem is easy: update `binutils` first. This will give you assembler that supports `.cfi` directives.

Once that's done, you should be able to configure and build glibc itself.

P.S. If you don't want to update the system binutils, you can configure binutils to use a different `--prefix`, and set your `PATH` to point to that alternate location while configuring and building glibc.

Comment: Thank you for your anwser,I will try what you say!